# Added item value changes after item property clear

Tags: c#, list

I have a list and when i clear the Notes property of the list after add it to list like below example it also clears the added item of stdList. I really didn't understand why? Please help me :(

```
List<Student> stdList = new List<Student>();
Student std = new Student();
std.Notes = new List<string>();
std.Notes.Add("EE");
stdList.Add(std);
std.Notes.Clear();
```

Comment: What language is this?  C#?  Java?

Comment: it is C#, since `string`, `List.Add` are in C#, and `String`, `List.add` are in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It changes because when you add `Student` object, it adds a reference to the object in the list. The reference you added will still point to the same object, which you modified. So any change to the object will be reflected in the list.

Here is demo:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("aa");

List<StringBuffer> list = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
list.add(sb);
System.out.println(list);

sb.append("bb");
System.out.println(list);

sb = null;
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
aa
aabb
aabb
```

And don't forget, when you deal with objects like Strings, which are immutable, a new object will be created on change operations. Your old object is still in the list while you got a new one elsewhere.

Comment: thanks. i updated the like below and now it works well. std = new Student();